# downloading Xampp and setting up a good working enviroment?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Currently I know a bit about HTML CSS and JavaScript. I now want to learn php and mySQL. So I've read around got some information but I can't really make clear the process I should be following to set up a good development environment.

First off my text editor is Brackets and I've downloaded Xampp onto my computer. I'm currently getting no errors when I open the control panel everything seems to be running fine. So here is my questions

1. What should I be doing next? is that it?
2. Is there a tutorial that I can follow that stops me asking for help on here?

My reason for posting is I did the same thing last time and then the next day I started getting errors so I've had to reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you must have read all about php. Let me lay out some basics for you. If everything is fine with control panel and you are able to start servers then type localhost in the browser and that'll confirm the installation process.

https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/

Follow that link in case you face problem.

To start with php go to any tutorial website, tutorialspoint etc. and learn some basics then make a folder in htcdocs and then access your files using localhost/yourfoldername/yourfile

localhost/phpmyadmin - to work on database.

Comment: is there anything I need to with sql, like password or am I ready to just go with now. Last time I got an error in mySQL and couldn't work out why?

Comment: Dafault account in MySQL is `root` and initially is has no password

Comment: localhost/phpmyadmin is where you can work with your database part. RiggsFolly is right, that is the default account but you can make users and databases there and you can even assign users specifically to database there. Please follow some simple tutorial at tutorialspoint etc. It'll not take much time to get started.